# Bootstrap carousel slide jumping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using a bootstrap carousel however it behaves a bit oddly. It looks like its spiking or jumping slides randomly.

You can find the carousel here, under the heading "What do our clients think"

https://staging-pptx-builder.herokuapp.com/

I've spent hours but could not resolve this issue.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has the same issue, it was a jquery vs boostrap conflict. I placed bootstrap under jquery and that fixed it.